# Convert expression from index to matrix/vector notation

Tags: matrix-calculus, index-notation

I am used to write lengthy expressions in index notation with the implied summation convention. Regrettably, I have convey my research to an audience which is more comfortable with the matrix/vector notation. For instance, I have to convert expressions like the following $\kappa_{r_1r_2}(\alpha)\kappa_{r_3r_4}(\alpha)\kappa_{r_2r_3r_4}(\alpha)$, where indices range in $1\ldots p$, $\alpha=\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p$ and $\kappa_{r_1r_2r_3}(\alpha)=\partial \kappa_{r_1r_2}/\partial\alpha_{r_3}$. Clearly $\kappa_{r_1r_2}(\alpha)$ is just a matrix of order $p$ and we can just call it $K(\alpha)$. The problem is to handle the three dimensional array $\kappa_{r_1r_2r_3}(\alpha)$ and then to take care of the summation. Regarding $\kappa_{r_1r_2r_3}(\alpha)$, I was thinking to write it as a block diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are $\partial K/\partial\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \partial K/\partial\alpha_{p}$, but I am not able to figure out if it is going to be of any help.

Do you have any hint and possibly a general rule to follow to convert the expression like the above (and even more complex) by using matrix/vector notation?

Comment: Whiy not just write $$\sum_{r1,r_2,r_3,\alpha}\kappa_{r_1r_2}(\alpha)\kappa_{r_3r_4}(\alpha)\kappa_{r_2r_3r_4}(\alpha)$$
I dont think anyone will find that confusing

Comment: Yes, of course that's a solution (but why $\alpha$ is appearing in the summation?). I forgot to mention that I would like to provide an expression in matrix/vector notation suitable for numerical implementation. Index notation is nice but when it comes to implementation it involves tons of for loops (which might be highly inefficient for certain programming languages).